# How get this date format CCYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss.sss-hh:mm

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

I am expecting to pass datetime to one of the service and the format should be as "CCYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss.sss-hh:mm". It must be datetime not string.

The variable to pass in the request is like: Request.Timestamp and is Datetime.

**What I have tried** *(got exception for all of these)*:

```
DateTime.Parse(DateTime.UtcNow.ToString(@"yyyy-MM-ddTHH\:mm\:ss.fffffffzzz"), null, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.AssumeLocal);
DateTime.Parse(DateTime.UtcNow.ToString(@"yyyy-MM-ddTHH\:mm\:ss.fffffffzzz"), null, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None)
DateTime.Parse(DateTime.UtcNow.ToString(@"yyyy-MM-ddTHH\:mm\:ss.fffffffzzz"), null, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.RoundtripKind)
DateTime.Parse(DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ss.sss-hh:mm"));
DateTime.Parse(DateTime.Now.ToString(@"yyyy-MM-ddTHH\:mm\:ss.fffffffzzz"), null, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.AssumeLocal);
```

Any help will be appreicated. Progarmming language I am using is C#.NET

Comment: Try [ParseExact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss.aspx) with the same format string you used for the .ToString() method.

Comment: They all return exception, Tried: DateTime.ParseExact(DateTime.Now.ToString(), @"yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ss.sss-hh:mm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture); DateTime.ParseExact(DateTime.Now.ToLongDateString(), @"yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ss.sss-hh:mm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture); DateTime.ParseExact(DateTime.Now.ToLongDateString(), @"yyyy-MM-ddTHH\:mm\:ss.fffffffzzz", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

Comment: Note that I said "with the **same format string** you **used for the .ToString() method**". But i guess i did not understand your question correctly when i was writing my first commend and phoog had a better grasp of your problem when answering it below :-)

Comment: Its working now, I used DateTime.Now.ToLocalTime();

Comment: @Hitin the ToLocalTime method no doubt includes the time zone offset correctly, which, as I mentioned in another comment, the verbatim format string in the service's specification does not (because the service uses "h" and "m" to specify the hour and minute of the time value in one place, and the hour and minute of the offset in another place).  I just had a chance to look it up, and it seems that .NET uses some number of "z" characters for that.  See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A `DateTime` value has no format.  The format is only significant when you represent the value as a string.  In other words, the requirements that it be formatted as "CCYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss.sss-hh:mm" and that it not be a string are mutually exclusive.

If it really needs to be a DateTime, you should just pass `DateTime.UtcNow` or `DateTime.Now`.  If it really needs to be in the specified format, then you should remove the DateTime.Parse calls, and just pass the correct format string to the ToString method.

The DateTime's value is stored as 64 bits.  Consider what you're doing by calling `DateTime.Parse(DateTime.Now.ToString(formatString))`: You're creating a formatted string based on the 64-bit DateTime value, then you're parsing that string into another 64-bit DateTime value.  It's rather a fools errand if you look at it that way.

Comment: This is what I have got to send according to the documents: Timestamp - type: dateTime, format: CCYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss.sss-hh:mm. If I pass DateTime.UtcNow or Now, I get error.

Comment: I have already tried passing UtcNow and Now, it always return error from the remote server.

Comment: @Hitin what error do you get?  We cannot help you resolve the error if we don't know what the error is.

Comment: The error was regarding the format and invalid string passed. However its working with DateTime.Now.ToLocalTime() now. Your exploitation was helpful and got it working, but I still don't understand, why it wouldn't work otherwise.

Comment: @Hitin I wonder if it isn't the format specifier in the requirement, which ends with "-hh:mm" to indicate the UTC offset.  When you include that in the ToString argument, however, the hour and minute of the time value will be repeated, however.  The parsing logic won't handle that correctly, of course.

Answer (score 3):

A `DateTime` is a binary data type, consisting of a count of 100-nanosecond ticks that represent the offset from the epoch of the internal calendar: 1 January 0001 CE at start-of-day (00:00:00.000). It doesn't have any representation other than what you give it when you format it for display.

Your code is converting it to a string in ISO 8601 format and then trying to parse that **back into a `DateTime` value**. The parse fails, because almost certainly that string representation is not the default representation for the current Culture.

If you need to pass it to a service in the expected format, Whatever is serializing it for sending it over the wire needs to format it correctly. That means either converting it to a string yourself, or ensure that the serializer knows the required format.

In either case, you probably want to turn it into a `DateTimeOffset`, though, instead of a `DateTime`, so the offset from UTC is an attribute on the object:

```
DateTimeOffset now = DateTime.SpecifyKind( DateTime.Now , DateTimeKind.Local ) ;
string formattedNow = now.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffzzz") ;
```

Which will produce something like this:

```
2015-06-19T16:01:27.384-07:00
```

Comment: How can I pass offset to the Response.TimeStamp as DateTime??